# Отсортировать числа в массиве в порядке возрастания

Tags: javascript

Как можно еще упростить данный код?

```
function numbersSort(array) {
  var done = false;
  while (!done) {
    done = true;
    for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i - 1] > array[i]) {
        done = false;
        var tmp = array[i - 1];
        array[i - 1] = array[i];
        array[i] = tmp;
      }
    }
  }

  return array;
}

console.log(numberSort([2, 35, 1, 7]));
```

Comment: т.е. надо без применения встроенных функций?

Comment: да, конечно. И избавится от этих false/true...если можно конечно так решить задачу. Также минимизировать было бы неплохо повторения array[i - 1]

Comment: Код хороший. Написан на устаревшем диалекте языка. Всё.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function numbersSort(a,next = 0) {  
  if (next == a.length) return a;
  for (let i=next; i<a.length; i++) {
    if (a[next] > a[i]) [a[next],a[i]] = [a[i],a[next]];
  }
  return numbersSort(a,next+1);  
}

console.log(numbersSort([2, 35, 1, -1, 7, 2]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот короткий вариант.

```
function numbersSort(array) {
  return array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
}
console.log(numbersSort([2, 35, 1, 7]));
```

Comment: надо без применения встроенных функций

Comment: Так бы и написал...

Comment: Комментарии читать надо...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Комментарии читать не надо, всё должно быть в вопросе.

Comment: @0xdb надо. там есть уточнения от других участников и наводящие вопросы.